# How to patch Magento bugs which are fixed in later versions

Tags: magento2, bug

We are running Magento2.2.6 and we are having a few session issues which are fixed in later version it seems, which we can see it from GitHub. But what is the procedure to get those commits should manually edit those files and apply it our current version? Following is the issue I would like to have in my current version, please suggest

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12362

Answer (score 0):

You can check which security patch included that fix and download it from this [Download page](https://www.magentocommerce.com/products/downloads/magento/)

Make sure you backup your website , and place your patch on the magento root using FTP/SFTP and execute it `sh security-patch-1.sh`

You can Find a [Detailed guide here](https://www.aitoc.com/blog/how-to-install-magento-2-security-patches/)